# Manhwa where the main character is half-human, hiding in the human world

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character’s father was a king and he fell in love with a human and his parents were killed in a coup, I think.

He then fled with the general of his father’s army, who posed as his grandmother in the human world.

He also joins an organization that kills those who invade, while hiding the fact that he’s half human.

Comment: When you say "human world," do you mean a different universe, or a different country in the same world? And did the "organization" you mentioned exist in the human world or the other world?

Comment: Someone using a different account with the same name as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, please merge your new account with the one you used to post this question by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from other users, leave comments within this thread, and mark an answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.